# SSL security display

Tags: tls, firefox

Why does Firefox not display the SSL logo when viewing secure sites, i.e. sites with HTTPS? It used to display at the bottom of the browser window previously but I just noticed that that bottom toolbar is not longer displayed. When I try to find the option to turn it on in Firefox, there is no such option.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "SSL logo". However, there is a *long-standing tradition* (nothing as official as a logo) of making some ongoing SSL explicit with an icon figuring a padlock. In recent versions, Firefox decided to put that padlock on the left of the URL bar, like this:

[image: Firefox URL bar with SSL]

The icon is actually redundant with the `https` protocol indication in the URL itself. However, many non-technically inclined people find the padlock icon easier to grasp.

The icon is also clickable; it will give details on the server's certificate, and the currently used SSL/TLS cryptographic algorithms.

Browsers are very susceptible to fashion; the padlock icon used to be in the bottom bar in the days of Netscape and early versions of Internet Explorer. It then gradually migrated up. Firefox is simply following the trend.

Answer (score 2):

You should see a lock icon in the address bar, left of the URL.

The icon is located in the same place on Chrome. It is located to the right of the URL in Internet Explorer.